# If I create a patch from local, uncommited work - it fails. If I commit my work, then create patch, it applies without fail. Why?

Tags: git, diff, patch

**I want to create a patch from the differences between my local code and the remote origin.**

I do this with:

```
git diff origin/myTestBranch > myPatch.patch
```

I go into a separate dir that cloned the same repo and has just pulled myTestBranch. I do so with

```
cd testPatchRepo
git clone ....
git checkout myTestBranch
```

When I try to apply the patch - it fails!

**However, if I commit my work and create a patch** with `git diff firstCommit ^...lastCommit > myPatch.patch` **the patch applies with no issues**...This doesn't solve my question, because I still want to be able to create a patch from my local, uncommitteed work.

Here is the patch created from local, uncommitted work:

```
 diff --git a/scripts b/scripts
index 8640468..adfabd7 160000
--- a/scripts
+++ b/scripts
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 8640468cc4ba87bebee0e9e26939361bcb3e3afa
+Subproject commit adfabd7bf11566f2888a4501bc557265f1172ac2-dirty
diff --git a/source/tutorial/install.txt b/source/tutorial/install.txt
index 5fee5f6..5ef6e4b 100644
--- a/source/tutorial/install.txt
+++ b/source/tutorial/install.txt
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@ Install {+bi-short+} on Windows

 .. include:: /includes/fact-bi-enterprise.rst

-Massaddie
+Maaaaassaddie
 To set up |bi|,
 follow the steps on this page.
```

The patch created after committing my change:

```
commit 983393a03262f8dccfd90b3c948751846ae583ae
Author: maddie <myemail>
Date:   Mon Dec 2 17:17:42 2019 -0500

    commit before make stage commit

diff --git a/source/tutorial/install.txt b/source/tutorial/install.txt
index 5fee5f6..5ef6e4b 100644
--- a/source/tutorial/install.txt
+++ b/source/tutorial/install.txt
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@ Install {+bi-short+} on Windows

 .. include:: /includes/fact-bi-enterprise.rst

-Massaddie
+Maaaaassaddie
 To set up |bi| with a business intelligence tool such as Tableau,
 follow the steps on this page.
```

Comment: Run `git pull --rebase origin ...` (`...` needs to be replaced with the branch name on a remote) before creating a patch. Also, do you really have a remote branch called *myTestBranch*? How did you clone and switch to it?

Comment: its actually caled test2, but fot the purposes of the post I gave it a better name. I fork a repo, clone it and switch to the branch with `git checkout test2`

Comment: I want to be able to do a git diff of whatever I have locally - even uncommitted work. `git pull --rebase origin/....` requires all my changes be committed or stashed

Comment: My point is that your base is not the same as on the cloned repo.

Comment: is there a way to verify that their bases are different before doing `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: after doing git pull --rebase, I am still getting patch failure

Comment: stash your local, uncommitted work and create a patch out of it as done [here](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2018/05/21/share-git-stash/)

Comment: @SaurabhPBhandari but if I also wanted the local, committed work. Say I made some commits. And then made some changes. How could I create a patch that captures both those (unpushed) commits and uncommitted changes?

Comment: @maddie, Does creating multiple patches help ? One for the committed changes (As mentioned in the question) and one for the local,uncommitted changes using stash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in general you can apply the output of `git diff` to another working tree, in this case you can't.  The reason is that `git diff` shows that your submodule is dirty: that is, it has uncommitted changes.  Since there's no way to represent these changes in the diff as it stands, any attempt to apply them will fail.

If you want to exclude these submodule changes, you can use `git diff --ignore-submodules`, which will ignore your submodules, whether modified or not.  If you want to include them recursively, you can use `git diff --submodule=diff`.  That patch won't update the submodule commits themselves, though it will change the submodule working tree, so it's not recommended.

Both of those should produce appliable patches.

Comment: Strangely, I am not getting applicable patches from either of those commands. I still get "error searching for..." when I do `git apply -v mypatch.patch`

Comment: Perhaps because the patch includes changes to local, unpushed commits - which the remote version doesn't have (and therefore cant find)

Comment: also im slightly confused - im not using submodules

Comment: @maddie You do — the directory `scripts` at the root of the main repo is a submodule, currently dirty (there is a new non pushed commit); you should push it and pull at the place where you're trying to apply the patch.